# TypeScript code doesn't produce visual output to html

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, webpack

I try to build TypeScript code for html viewing, I have the following code:
console.log('hello world');
After building code with "yarn build", "node ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack --mode development"
run it with "node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server --mode development "
Also html file generated by builder is included in src directory and webpackbundle.js is also there:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Canvas demo</title>
    <script defer src="webpackbundle.js"></script></head>
<body>
    <script src="webpackbundle.js"></script>
    <p id="clear">above</p>
</body>
</html>
```

But after running there is no expected output "hello world" on html, only "above" as stated as initial html, so it seems that app isn't viewed by running html

My webpack.config.js loks like:

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require("path");
module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: './game.tsx',
    output: { 
        path : path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        filename: 'webpackbundle.js'  
    }, 
    ...
    plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        path : path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        template: "index.html",
        hash: true, // This is useful for cache busting
        filename: 'index.html'
    })]
}  //also have rules for typescript and resolve, port specification
```

In src webpackbundle.js.map is generated and webpackbundle.js has corresponding console.log('hello world') code, but there is no related output in html

Could anybody advise on how to make code output visible in html?

Comment: Console.log prints to console (in your developer tools) not to html though?

Comment: Okay, but I generally tried special tools for printing in html and effect is the same, no effect

Comment: What are 'special tools' to print to html? You can't print to html, you have to create Dom nodes if you want anything displayed.

Comment: You can print to html canvas as example, in general question is that some methods from scratch doesn't produce output in html element, for example I call method to draw png image on canvas and it doesn't work, only blank page without png is shown

Comment: You should really revise your question and elaborate on what you want to achieve and what you already tried. Your html does not include any canvas or anything that indicates that you don't want to create standard dom nodes. As is, I don't think anyone can help you on your question.